# How to use Zingchart in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, zingchart

i want to use **zingChart** in my project using javascript can anyone have idea how to do ?

Comment: Off topic to SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put this code ..

```
<script src="https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    zingchart.MODULESDIR = "https://cdn.zingchart.com/modules/";
    ZC.LICENSE = ["569d52cefae586f634c54f86dc99e6a9", "ee6b7db5b51705a13dc2339db3edaf6d"];
  </script>
```

Now you are able to use zingChart.. read more [ZingChart](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart/)

Comment: if u still finding then read blog it has very good documentations :)